# Excel Pivot Table Rolling calculated column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, analysis

So I have made a pivot table using the data format below

```
Date      Item

3-1-20    Pasta
3-1-20    Burger
4-1-20    Pizza
4-1-20    Pasta
5-1-20    Pizza
6-1-20    Burger
6-1-20    Tikka
 .          .
 .          .
 .          .
```

And the pivot table format is as below

```
Item       3-1-20     4-1-20    5-1-20    6-1-20

Pasta        1          1         0         0
Burger       1          0         0         1
Pizza        0          1         1         0
Tikka        0          0         0         1
```

I am using **Count** function to calculate no of items per day and displaying them on day basis column wise.

I would like to add a calculated column to show rolling difference between two previous date, for example:

```
Item       3-1-20     4-1-20    5-1-20    6-1-20   Diff

Pasta        1          1         0         0       0
Burger       1          0         0         1       1
Pizza        0          1         1         0      -1
Tikka        0          0         0         1       1
```

I can't understand how to do so. Can anybody please guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Count of Item to your pivot table a second time. Then right click the new measure and select Show Values As>Difference From

[image]

Change it so the base field is Date and the Base item is (previous). Like this:

[image]

If you want, you can type a new name for each measure, so it looks a bit nicer:

[image]

Comment: That seems to work. Though I would have liked for only 1 column to appear and that too at the end. Thanks anyways !!